# Colours for geom_histogram

Tags: r, graph, colors, ggplot2, gradient

I have a dataset that I want to plot with ggplot using geom_histogram (data below). I am having issues with trying to get a gradient colour scheme.

```r
structure(list(UserID = c(39120L, 39536L, 39550L, 39627L, 39632L, 
39709L, 39971L, 39988L, 39990L, 40062L, 40065L, 40065L, 40066L, 
40142L, 40142L, 40143L, 40161L, 40193L, 40364L, 40437L, 40439L, 
40440L, 40451L, 40453L, 40665L, 40665L, 40668L, 40751L, 40843L, 
40843L, 40843L, 40846L, 40846L, 40847L, 40847L, 40850L, 40850L, 
40884L, 40884L, 40884L, 40896L, 40900L, 40902L, 40903L, 40905L, 
40963L, 40966L, 40966L, 40967L, 40967L, 40969L, 40971L, 40971L, 
40985L, 40985L, 41010L, 41079L, 41080L, 41080L, 41081L, 41093L, 
41108L, 41110L, 41111L, 41113L, 41114L, 41133L, 41137L, 41138L, 
41140L, 41161L, 41162L, 41182L, 41186L, 41260L), sales = c(0.0119, 
0.0032, 0.0091, 0.0098, 0.0086, 0.0101, 0.0107, 0.0111, 0.0085, 
0.0178, 0.0069, 0.0055, 0.0133, 0.0112, 0.0084, 0.0141, 0.0159, 
0.01, 0.0054, 0.0129, 0.011, 0.0116, 0.0099, 0.0134, 0.0046, 
0.004, 0.0076, 0.005, 0.0027, 0.0037, 3e-04, 0.022, 0.012, 0.0082, 
0.0108, 0.0092, 0.0101, 0.0016, 0.0082, 0.0035, 0.007, 0.0098, 
0.0146, 0.0074, 0.005, 0.0152, 0.0046, 0.0032, 0.0028, 0, 0.0179, 
0.0185, 0.0095, 0.0401, 0.0163, 0.0085, 0.0099, 0.0064, 0.0067, 
0.0052, 0.0191, 0.0118, 0.0054, 0.0111, 0.0065, 0.0124, 0.0047, 
0.0111, 0.0063, 0.0072, 0.0062, 0.0091, 0.0066, 0.0169, 0.0071
), salesfromtarget = c(0.214285714285714, -0.673469387755102, 
-0.0714285714285714, 0, -0.122448979591837, 0.0306122448979592, 
0.0918367346938777, 0.13265306122449, -0.13265306122449, 0.816326530612245, 
-0.295918367346939, -0.438775510204082, 0.357142857142857, 0.142857142857143, 
-0.142857142857143, 0.438775510204082, 0.622448979591837, 0.0204081632653062, 
-0.448979591836735, 0.316326530612245, 0.122448979591837, 0.183673469387755, 
0.010204081632653, 0.36734693877551, -0.530612244897959, -0.591836734693878, 
-0.224489795918367, -0.489795918367347, -0.724489795918367, -0.622448979591837, 
-0.969387755102041, 1.24489795918367, 0.224489795918367, -0.163265306122449, 
0.102040816326531, -0.0612244897959184, 0.0306122448979592, -0.836734693877551, 
-0.163265306122449, -0.642857142857143, -0.285714285714286, 0, 
0.489795918367347, -0.244897959183673, -0.489795918367347, 0.551020408163265, 
-0.530612244897959, -0.673469387755102, -0.714285714285714, -1, 
0.826530612244898, 0.887755102040817, -0.0306122448979592, 3.09183673469388, 
0.663265306122449, -0.13265306122449, 0.010204081632653, -0.346938775510204, 
-0.316326530612245, -0.469387755102041, 0.948979591836735, 0.204081632653061, 
-0.448979591836735, 0.13265306122449, -0.336734693877551, 0.26530612244898, 
-0.520408163265306, 0.13265306122449, -0.357142857142857, -0.26530612244898, 
-0.36734693877551, -0.0714285714285714, -0.326530612244898, 0.724489795918367, 
-0.275510204081633)), .Names = c("UserID", "sales", "salesfromtarget"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 72L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 93L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using this code I am trying to use `scale_fill_brewer` to get a gradient scheme (but it doesn't have to be this specific one, it was just an example of something not working). All of the bars are grey and ideally they would not be grey. Best case scenario I wanted to use something along the lines of `scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue")` (again this doesn't work for me). I feel like I'm missing something fundamental with ggplot2.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(ggthemes)

ggplot(repex, aes(x = salesfromtarget)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = .1, alpha = 0.5, colour = "white") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
guides(fill = FALSE) +
theme_solarized() +
ggtitle("Standard Distribution of Sales") + xlab("Sales") + ylab("Frequency") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 13, colour = "black", face = "bold", vjust = 1)) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", vjust = -.005), 
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", vjust = 0.2),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1.5, 1.5, by = .25),
                 limits = c(-1.5, 1.5), labels = percent)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the "fill" variable in the aes() section:

```
ggplot(repex, aes(x=salesfromtarget, fill=..x..))
    +geom_histogram(binwidth=.1)
    +scale_fill_gradient("Legend",low = "green", high = "blue")
```

[image]

Since the histogram bars are the count of each x-axis value, if you want to use the original x value you should use "**..x..**". You can fill with the histogram count using "**..count..**":

```
ggplot(repex, aes(x=salesfromtarget, fill=..count..))
    +geom_histogram(binwidth=.1)
    +scale_fill_gradient("Legend",low = "green", high = "blue")
```

[image]